# Передать значение PHP в JS

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте!

У меня имеется страница с каталогом товаром, где перед добавлением товара в корзину можно указать произвольное количество единиц товара, но максимальное количество товара, которое можно добавить, подгружается из базы данных с помощью PHP в max="":

```
<input type="text" value="1" min="1" max="<?=$product['nalichie']?>">
```

Далее посмотрите, пожалуйста, пример - [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/bowp77vb/12/)

Я же хочу сделать следующее:

Записывать максимальное число товара в переменную js, которое можно добавить в корзину:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var nalichie ='<?=$product['nalichie']?';</script>
```

Получается эта строчка js выводится у каждого товара, но со своим числом. То есть я передаю значение PHP в JS.

Сейчас у меня передаётся значение переменной всегда одно и то же, а не того товара на который кликнул прибавить +1 товар, например. Проверяю я это с помощью `alert(nalichie);`

Для чего я делаю такую проверку. Ведь по сути для поля input и так задаётся максимальное число, которое может ввести человек и проверяется это все с помощью js. Но стоит лишь в панели разработчика поменять максимальное число на произвольное своё, js будет принимать новое значение из **max="..."**, а так не хотелось бы.

Думаю данное решение пригодится многим. Может посоветуете другой способ. Надеюсь на Вашу помощь:) Буду сердечно благодарен!

Comment: Так и не понял, для чего эти танцы с бубном. Во время загрузки страницы формируется список товаров с указанием максимального доступного для заказа количества. Больше выбрать нельзя. При добавлении в корзину (второй вариант - при подтверждении заказа) проверяем средствами php правильность всех данных. Зачем сложности? Ну пусть кто-то хоть до одури меняет ваш HTML. Вам-то с того ничего. Главное проверить потом всё на сервере - средствами php.

Comment: @n.osennij Вот хочется такой метод проверки. В корзине тоже самое применю. Решил так, потому что планирую в будущем проверять значение остатка товара онлайн (постоянное обновление переменной), так как могут оформлять заказы пока человек сидит на странице и думает сколько же товара ему заказать. Но это отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @ Ну тогда сделайте ajax. Когда человек вводит число заказываемых товаров - отправляем запрос на php, который проверяет, сколько товара на данных момент осталось, и не хочет ли человек заказать больше.

Comment: @n.osennij Тоже верно. Но, как это сделать я не знаю. Знал бы - сделал:) А сейчас раз уж открыл вопрос, хочется его решить для себя. Надеюсь на помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из небольшого обсуждения в комментариях пришли к варианту следующему: использовать ajax. Лично мне кажется, что это не оправдано. Ну да ладно.

1. Подключить jQuery к html (подключается как js)
2. Каждый товар в скрытом поле должен иметь свой идентификатор из БД. Желательно значение из индексируемого поля. Но проще всего будет **добавить ИД_товара в value каждый кнопки** (именно в вашем случае) - это будет в примере.
3. При увеличении количества заказанных товаров хватаем ИД товара и отправляем на проверку php скрипту с помощью ajax.

```js
jQuery(".КНОПКА").click(function(event) { // .КНОПКА - класс кнопок, нажатие на которые отслеживаем
    id=$(this).val(); //берём value кнопки. Там мы храним ИД товара
    aj("handler.php", false, "html", {"id": id}, s_handler); //Обратите внимание на false (можно на true) - синхронно или асинхронно!
});

function s_handler(result) {
    //обрабатываем ответ
}

function aj(url, async, datatype, data, success) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        async: async,
        //timeout: 20000, //Время ожидания выполнения запроса 20с.
        dataType: datatype,
        data: data,
        success: success,
        error: function(err){console.log(err);}
    });
}
```

На стороне php делаем все проверки и высылаем какой-то ответ. Который принимает тот же ajax (функция s_handler) и что-то делает.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53507/discussion-on-answer-by-n-osennij---php--js).